# Using form_for returns: undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting this error when trying to use form_for:

_feedback_form.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @support, :html => { :method => :post } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :class => "quick_feedback_form", :input_html => { :maxlength => 450 } %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :email, :value => current_user.email %>
    <div><%= f.submit "Send!", :disable_with => "Sending...", :class => "button white" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Running this returns this error:

```
NoMethodError in Pages#guardian

Showing /home/alex/myapp/app/views/supports/_feedback_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
```

The @support variable is created and is not nil - I can see it from the log. This was also working nicely in Rails 3.0, and now after migrating to Rails 3.2 this is somehow broken.

Here is a class of Support variable. This is used for sending email feedback to the admin:

```
class Support < ActiveRecord::Base
include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_presence_of :content 
  # to deal with form, you must have an id attribute
  attr_accessor :id, :email, :sender_name, :content

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |key, value|
      self.send("#{key}=", value)
    end
    @attributes = attributes
  end

  def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
    @attributes[key]
  end

  def to_key
  end

  def save
    if self.valid?
      Feedback.support_notification(self).deliver
      return true
    end
    return false
  end
end
```

Tried different things but still can't see what is wrong here. Rails 3.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is your `to_key` method. Is there a reason you're defining this method here? It's already defined in `ActiveRecord::Base`, so you're overriding the internal method. If you just take it out of your model, that should fix your problem.

If you do want to define `to_key` here for some reason, remember that for `persisted` models (e.g. `ActiveRecord` models), it should return an array with the key attributes of the model.  So it should look something like this:

```
def to_key
  [self.id]
end
```

And why are you including `ActiveModel::Validations`? This is done for you in `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I just commented out that to_key method, and it worked! Got to use less copy-pasted code :D that was probably from some example from the old Rails.

Comment: I ran into this problem when I was playing around with form objects.  For me, adding a to_key method to my form object solved the problem.  Thanks!